# MongoDB, $[<identifier>] Can I get element from arrayFilters?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update my json array.

current json value is

```
       inventory: {
          _id: '1234'
          inventory: [
             {
                itemIndex: 0,
                count: 0
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 1,
                count: 0
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 5,
                count: 0
             },     
             {
                itemIndex: 10,
                count: 0
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 11,
                count: 0
             },
          ]
        }
```

I want to increase 'itemIndex' field by array value's count.

the result would be

```
var arr = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,4,5] // get random array
       inventory: {
          _id: '1234'
          inventory: [
             {
                itemIndex: 0,
                count: 4 // Increase 4, Since arr value 0 has appear 4 times 
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 1,
                count: 3 // // Increase 3, Since arr value 1 has appear 3 times
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 5,
                count: 1 // Increase 1, Since arr value 5 has appear 1 times
             },     
             {
                itemIndex: 10,
                count: 0
             },
             {
                itemIndex: 11,
                count: 0
             },
          ]
        }
```

I'm trying to this code.

```
        var filter = { _id: id };

        await User.updateOne(filter,
            {
                $inc: {
                    "clubInventories.$[elem].amount": 1
                }
            }, 
            {
                arrayFilters: [
                    { "elem.itemIndex": { $in: itemIndex } },
                ]
            },
        )
```

This code only increase 1 by 1, not including duplicated value.
but, I want to increase 'itemIndex' according to count of values.

Please help.

Comment: Where does the random array come from? Is it available in the client before submitting the update, or is it discovered server side during the update?

Comment: it update after GET request from client side, in server side during the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way this can be done is to dynamically build the update object and the array filters on the client side based on the array.

Starting with all the counts at 0:

```
replset:PRIMARY> db.updtest.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "inventory" : [
        {
            "itemIndex" : 0,
            "count" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 1,
            "count" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 5,
            "count" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 10,
            "count" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 11,
            "count" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

And the input array:

```
let arr = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,3,4,5]
```

First iterate the array to count the occurrences:

```
let counted=arr.reduce(function(a,b){
   if(a[b]===undefined) a[b] = 0;
   a[b]++;
   return a;
},{})
```

Use that calculated object to build an array filter for each distinct value from the array:

```
let filters = Object.keys(counted).map(function(k){
   let f={};
   f['index'+k+'.itemIndex'] = parseInt(k); 
   return f;
})
```

And construct the increment object with the count of each distinct value

```
let increments = Object.keys(counted).reduce(function(u,k){
   u['inventory.$[index'+k+'].count'] = counted[k]; 
   return u
},{})
```

Then pass the dynamically generated objects with the update command:

```
db.updtest.update({_id:'1234'},{$inc:increments},{arrayFilters:filters})
```

Giving the result:

```
replset:PRIMARY> db.updtest.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "1234",
    "inventory" : [
        {
            "itemIndex" : 0,
            "count" : 4
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 1,
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 5,
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 10,
            "count" : 0
        },
        {
            "itemIndex" : 11,
            "count" : 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I understood how it works. really helpful, many thanks.

Comment: nice solution, try to use `updatedMany()` instead of `update()` because its deprecated in mongoose!